# Pandas groupby multiple columns, with pct_change

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find the period-over-period growth in `Value` for each unique group, grouped by (`Company`, `Group`, and `Date`).

```
Company Group Date     Value
A       X     2015-01  1
A       X     2015-02  2
A       X     2015-03  1.5
A       XX    2015-01  1
A       XX    2015-02  1.5
A       XX    2015-03  0.75
A       XX    2015-04  1
B       Y     2015-01  1
B       Y     2015-02  1.5
B       Y     2015-03  2
B       Y     2015-04  3
B       YY    2015-01  2
B       YY    2015-02  2.5
B       YY    2015-03  3
```

I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Company','Group']).pct_change()
```

but this returns all NaN.

The result I'm looking for is:

```
Company Group Date     Value/People
A       X     2015-01  NaN
A       X     2015-02  1.0
A       X     2015-03  -0.25
A       XX    2015-01  NaN
A       XX    2015-02  0.5
A       XX    2015-03  -0.5
A       XX    2015-04  0.33
B       Y     2015-01  NaN
B       Y     2015-02  0.5
B       Y     2015-03  0.33
B       Y     2015-04  0.5
B       YY    2015-01  NaN
B       YY    2015-02  0.25
B       YY    2015-03  0.2
```

Comment: Your issue here is that **you want to groupby multiple columns**, then do a `pct_change()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you want to get your date into the row index and groups/company into the columns

```
d1 = df.set_index(['Date', 'Company', 'Group']).Value.unstack(['Company', 'Group'])
d1
```

[image]

then use `pct_change`

```
d1.pct_change()
```

[image]

OR

with groupby

```
df['pct'] = df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Company', 'Group']).Value.pct_change()
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure the `groupby` method works as intended as of Pandas 0.23.4 at least.

```
df['pct'] = df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Company', 'Group']).Value.pct_change()
```

Produces this, which is incorrect for purposes of the question:

[image: Incorrect Outcome]

The Index+Stack method still works as intended, but you need to do additional merges to get it into the original form requested.

```
d1 = df.set_index(['Date', 'Company', 'Group']).Value.unstack(['Company', 'Group'])
d1 = d1.pct_change().stack([0,1]).reset_index()
df = df.merge(d1, on=['Company', 'Group', 'Date'], how='left')
df.rename(columns={0: 'pct'}, inplace=True)
df
```

[image: Correct Outcome]

Comment: This appears to be fixed again as of 0.24.0, so be sure to update to that version.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Pct_Change'] = df.groupby(['Company','Group'])['Value'].pct_change()
```