# Pandas 0.23 groupby and pct change not returning expected value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For each `Name` in the following dataframe I'm trying to find the percentage change from one `Time` to the next of the `Amount` column:

[image]

Code to create the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Ali', 'Ali', 'Ali', 'Cala', 'Cala', 'Cala', 'Elena', 'Elena', 'Elena'],
                   'Time': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Amount': [24, 52, 34, 95, 98, 54, 32, 20, 16]})

df.sort_values(['Name', 'Time'], inplace = True)
```

The first approach I tried (based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273251/pandas-groupby-with-pct-change)) used `groupby` and `pct_change`:

```
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Amount'].pct_change()
```

With the result:

[image]

This doesn't seem to be grouping by the name because it is the same result as if I had used no `groupby` and called `df['Amount'].pct_change()`. According to the [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html) for `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change`, the above approach should work to calculate the percentage change of each value to the previous value within a group.

For a second approach I used `groupby` with `apply` and `pct_change`:

```
df['pct_change_with_apply'] = df.groupby('Name')['Amount'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change())
```

With the result:

[image]

This time all the percentage changes are correct.

Why does the `groupby` and `pct_change` approach not return the correct values, but using `groupby` with `apply` does?

**Edit January 28, 2018**: This behavior has been corrected in the latest version of Pandas, 0.24.0. To install run `pip install -U pandas`.

Comment: Weird, `df.groupby(['Name'])['Amount'].pct_change()` is giving me the correct result. Am I just missing something?

Comment: @ALollz what version of pandas?

Comment: I can confirm bugged behavior.  Pandas 0.23.1

Comment: I'm using 0.22.0

Comment: @caseWestern I'm guessing this is a bug in new version.  Please confirm your version.  Pandas is trapping the `pct_change` method on the `groupby` object and botching it up.

Comment: Already reported https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21621

Comment: Using Pandas 0.23.1. Sorry if this is an issue that has already been reported!

Comment: Please don't apologize (-: This is a good question.  I'm just verifying that this is a bug and has been reported.  And I found out it was reported because I was going to report it.  I wouldn't have even tried to report it if you didn't bring it up.

Comment: It's interesting because `diff` does not have this issue. For example, `df.groupby('Name')['Amount'].diff()` returns the expected behavior.

Comment: This has been fixed in a [pull request for Pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21235). If you install the most recent version of the [Pandas master branch on GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) you can get the fix. Otherwise, I think this fix will be in the next release of the Pandas library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted by @piRSquared in the comments; this is due to a [bug filed on Github under issue #21621](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21621). It already looks to be solved in milestone `0.24.0` (due 2018-12-31). My version (`0.23.4`) still displayed this bugged behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Can you confirm this is solved in the latest release of Pandas?

Comment: `0.24.0` has been moved to 2019-01-31.

Comment: I can confirm `0.24.0` is out now and that the issue has been solved. Run `pip install --upgrade pandas` to get the latest release.