# pandas pct_change(), Indexed on date with country grouped data gives incorrect outcome

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, ipython

pandas version: 0.24.2

I'm trying to find growth rate by date for each unique group (country). My data looks like this:

'''

```
date        country  metric1        
2020-01-03  AD       45793
2020-03-28  US       13254524
2020-02-04  HT       224126
2020-02-04  AQ       106564
2020-01-11  LI       69168
2020-01-02  AD       47855
2020-03-23  MW       45795
2020-03-18  GM       38205
2020-03-06  CI       488755
```

'''

If I run:

```
df['metric1_change'] = df.groupby(['country'])['metric1'].pct_change()
```

The outcome is incorrect and the pct_change does not relate to the previous values. See example outcome:

```
date        country   metric1   metric1_change
2020-01-01  AD        41550     0.048289
2020-01-02  AD        47855     0.184149
2020-01-03  AD        45793     0.255084
```

The first date is 2020-01-01 so the percentage change there should already be NaN and the others are completely incorrect.

If I sort before with:

`df.sort_values(by=['country','date'])`

I also do not receive the correct output:

```
date        country  metric1    metric1_change
2020-01-01  AD       41550      0.046916
2020-01-02  AD       47855      0.197273
2020-01-03  AD       45793      0.674088
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

I have seen this question [Pandas groupby and pct change not returning expected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085919/pandas-groupby-and-pct-change-not-returning-expected-value) but the apply doesn't help me and I think i'm making a more basic mistake.

Comment: How working solution if sorting before? By `df = df.sort_values(['country','date'])` and then `df['metric1_change'] = df.groupby(['country'])['metric1'].pct_change()`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander sorry for not clarifying but the sample is an extract of a much larger dataset which does include 'AD'.

Comment: @jezrael Sorting doesn't help, I'll add it to the question to show.

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: @jezrael pandas: 0.24.2

Comment: @WvonR - I guess bug

Comment: @JoshFriedlander added AD to sample data.

Comment: Doesn't reproduce, using the same pandas version. I get `-0.043088` for the `metric1_change`, which is correct. Maybe you have an error somewhere else