# Pandas - Evaluating row wise operation per entity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe as shown below

```
Entity class   7dayAvg  10dayAvg
A      class1   50      100
A      class2   25      200
B      class1   40      80
B      class2   80      200
```

The problem at hand requires finding the percentage difference(7dayAvg and for 10dayAvg) between class1 and class2 for each entity A and B. Hence, the answer should be:

```
Entity  7day%Diff     10day%diff
A       (50-25)/50    (100-200)/100
B       (40-80)/40    (80-200)/80
```

Comment: Doing "operation per entity" just means `.groupby('Entity')` ; you could also use `.join()`. In your case the operation is an aggregation, so `df.groupby('Entity').agg(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby multiple columns, with pct\_change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273251/pandas-groupby-multiple-columns-with-pct-change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `groupby().pct_change()`:

```
df[['Entity']].join(-df.groupby('Entity')[['7dayAvg', '10dayAvg']]
                       .pct_change().dropna(),
                    how='inner')
```

Output:

```
  Entity  7dayAvg  10dayAvg
1      A      0.5      -1.0
3      B     -1.0      -1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to attempt to code it; here are hints for you; post your code attempt in the edited question if you get stuck:

- `groupby('Entity')`, then use `.aggregate()` with a custom aggregation defied by a dictionary
- you want to compute `7day%Diff` which is the relative difference in `7dayAvg`
- ditto `10day%diff` on `10dayAvg`

It's a bad idea to use special or magic characters in column (or index) names, so I'd use the names `7day_diff, 10day_diff` or even just `diff_7d, diff_10d` for clarity and simplicitity. (See also [PEP-8 style recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'entity': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'b'}, 'class': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2}, '7da': {0: 50, 1: 25, 2: 40, 3: 80}, '10da': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 80, 3: 200}})
```

Another option is two divide two data frames, one with the difference

```
>>> x.set_index('entity').groupby('entity').diff().dropna()*-1
        class   7da   10da
entity
a        -1.0  25.0 -100.0
b        -1.0 -40.0 -120.0
```

Another with the denominator:

```
>>> x.set_index('entity').groupby('entity').first()
        class  7da  10da
entity
a           1   50   100
b           1   40    80
```

Giving:

```
>>> ((x.set_index('entity').groupby('entity').diff().dropna()*-1) / (x.set_index('entity').groupby('entity').first())).drop('class', axis = 1)
        7da  10da
entity
a       0.5  -1.0
b      -1.0  -1.5
```